# Issue Related to repetition of button in form React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am creating a Questionnaire in ReactNative, when fetching data from firebase and displaying it the submit button is coming after each Question. I want the button to be displayed at the end if I remove the button from the  tag and put it in another  tag then it displays one time, but the forms do not get submitted. The Problem occurs after the second return in the code.
My code is:

```
./DetailsScreen
 

import './App.css';
import firebase from './firebase';
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import { storage } from "./firebase";
import logo from "./assets/front.png";
const DetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [QuestionD, setQuestionD] = useState("");
  const [choice1, setchoice1] = useState("");
  const [choice2, setchoice2] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handChange = e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const fileType = file["type"];
      const validImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg","image/png"];
      if (validImageTypes.includes(fileType)) {
        setError("");
        setImage(file);
      } else {
        setError("Please select an image to upload");
      }
    }
  };

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    if (image) {
      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {
          const progress = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          setProgress(progress);
        },
        error => {
          setError(error);
        },
        () => {
          storage
            .ref("images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              setUrl(url);
              setProgress(0);
            });
        }
      );
    } else {
      setError("Error please choose an image to upload");
    }
  };

  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
 
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoader(true);
  firebase.firestore().collection("Response")
  .add({
            choice1:choice1,
            choice2:choice2,
            message : message,
            QuestionD:QuestionD,
            timestamp : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        
          })
          .then(() => {
            setLoader(false);
            alert("Your form has been submitted");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message);
            setLoader(false);
          });

        setchoice1("");
        setchoice2("");
        setQuestionD("");
        setMessage("");
         };
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getBooks();
  }, []);
  const getBooks = async () => {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() *  100) + 1)
    const response=firebase.firestore().collection('Humemah')
    .where("ID",">=" , random)
    .limit(10)
    const data=await response.get();

    console.log(data.docs);
    setBooks(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };
                 
  return (
    <div className="header">
    <h1>QUESTIONNAIRE</h1>
    {
     books.map((doc, index) => {
    return(
      <form className="Question" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        
        
        <label className='fields' onsubmit={(e) => setQuestionD(e.target.value)} value={doc.QuestionD}>QUESTION: {String(doc.QuestionD)}
        </label>
        
        <br>
        </br>
       
       <div>
        <label className='fields' >YES</label>
        <input type="radio" id value={doc.Choice1} onsubmit={(e) => setchoice1(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div >
        <label className='fields'>NO</label>
        <input type="radio"  value={doc.Choice2} onChange={(e) => setchoice2(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div className='fields'>
        <label className='box'> MESSAGE: </label> </div>
          <textarea
            placeholder="Message"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
   
  <br></br>
  <div>
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={handChange} />{" "}
        <button onClick={handleUpdate}> UPLOAD </button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "20px" }}>
        {progress > 0 ? <progress value={progress} max="20" /> : ""}
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</p>
      </div>
      <div className='fields'>
      {url ? (
        <img src={url} width='150' height=' 150' />
      ) : (
        <img  width='100' height=' 100' />
      )}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className='button'>
    <button type="submit" > SUMBIT </button>
    </div>
    </form>
    )
    })
    }
    </div>
    );
}
export default DetailsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit button is working only inside form tag right, so don't change submit button to another tag instead show submit button only in last element by comparing books array length and item index like shown below

```
{(index == (books.length - 1)) && <button type="submit" > SUMBIT </button>}
```